# DIV interna sobrepõe a externa

Tags: css3

Tenho uma `div` interna que sobrepõe a externa.

Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe na imagem acima que a `div` externa não envolve toda a interna.

**HTML e CSS**

```css
.conteudo{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu{
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.lista{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.lista-recursos{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}
.link-lista{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="conteudo">
    
<strong><div class="menu">Lista - Guia comercial</div></strong>
    
    <?php
    $lista=mysqli_query($con,"select id,titulo,status from empresas");
    while($painel_lista=mysqli_fetch_array($lista))
    {
    ?>
     <div class="lista">
    <?php echo $painel_lista['titulo']; ?>
     </div>
    
     <div class="lista-recursos">
     <a href="editar-guia-comercial.php?id=<?php echo $painel_lista['id']; ?>" class="link-lista">EDITAR</a>
     </div>
    
     <div class="lista-recursos">
     <?php 
     if ($painel_lista['status'] == 1) {
      ?>
       <a href="status-guia-comercial.php?id=<?php echo $painel_lista['id']; ?>&status_alterar=2" class="link-lista">ATIVADO</a>
      <?php
      } else {
      ?>
       <a href="status-guia-comercial.php?id=<?php echo $painel_lista['id']; ?>&status_alterar=1" class="link-lista">DESATIVADO</a>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
     </div>
    
     <div class="lista-recursos">
     <a href="confirmar-deletar.php?id=<?php echo $painel_lista['id']; ?>" class="link-lista">DELETAR</a>
     </div>
    
     <div class="lista-recursos">
     <a href="banner-guia-comercial.php?id=<?php echo $painel_lista['id']; ?>" class="link-lista">BANNER</a>
     </div>
    
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Podes colocar aqui o HTML renderizado? ie o que chega ao browser, e não PHP.

Comment: cria uma div no final assim: <div style="clear:both"></div> tem que ser a ultima da lista

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema é que vc está usando `float:left` nos elementos filhos do `container`. Quando vc coloca `float` nos Filhos o Pai perde a referencia dos valores do `box-model` desses elementos, pois agora eles estão "flutuando" no dom.

Uma das técnicas para resolver isso é colocando `overflow:auto` no Pai `container`, assim mesmo o Filho tendo `float` ele não vai "fugir" ao escopo do Pai.
 ***OBS:*** Apenas retirei as tags PHP para melhor renderizar no exemplo.

Veja o exemplo como fica.

```css
  .conteudo {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 10px auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  .menu {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  .lista {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .lista-recursos {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .link-lista {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
```

```html
<div class="conteudo">

  <strong>
    <div class="menu">Lista - Guia comercial</div>
  </strong>


  <div class="lista">
    titulo
  </div>

  <div class="lista-recursos">
    <a href="editar-guia-comercial.php?id=<?php echo $painel_lista['id']; ?>" class="link-lista">EDITAR</a>
  </div>

  <div class="lista-recursos">

    <a href="status-guia-comercial.php?id=<?php echo $painel_lista['id']; ?>&status_alterar=2" class="link-lista">ATIVADO</a>

    <a href="status-guia-comercial.php?id=<?php echo $painel_lista['id']; ?>&status_alterar=1" class="link-lista">DESATIVADO</a>

  </div>

  <div class="lista-recursos">
    <a href="confirmar-deletar.php?id=<?php echo $painel_lista['id']; ?>" class="link-lista">DELETAR</a>
  </div>

  <div class="lista-recursos">
    <a href="banner-guia-comercial.php?id=<?php echo $painel_lista['id']; ?>" class="link-lista">BANNER</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

**DICA:** Nessa resposta tem alguns detalhes que podem de interessar apesar de não exatamente o mesmo problema. [Porque margin-top afeta a div pai](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/336980/porque-margin-top-afeta-a-div-pai/336991#336991)