# Porque margin-top afeta a div pai

Tags: css, margin

Porque quando dou um margin-top no elemento filho isso afeta o elemento pai? Veja exemplo abaixo:

```css
body{
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
}
.topo{
 width: calc(100% - 20px);
 max-width: 1200px;
 height: 130px;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: #000000;
}
.topo_caixa{
 width: calc(100% - 20px);
 height: calc(100% - 20px);
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 10px;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<div class="topo">
<div class="topo_caixa">
</div>
</div>
```

E qual a melhor forma de fazer isso que quero? Alinhar essa caixa de dentro ao centro, sei que tem inúmeras formas, mas existe alguma mais indicada?

Comment: Amigo, dê uma olhada neste [link do SOe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div)

Comment: Valeu, então a resposta é que é um bug mesmo, certo? Não é algo errado, não tem uma explicação lógica, é isso?

Comment: Caio vou copiar parte dessa resposta e colocar aqui pra vc com mais uns detalhes, vou remover o voto para fechar

Comment: Acora a resposta ficou mais completa :) tmj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vc está tendo um problema conhecido como **Colapso de Margem** ou ***Margin Collapsing***. Esse "bug" já foi descrito e é bem documentado inclusive. Vc pode se informar mais sobre esse assunto nessa documentação da própria Mozilla. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/margin_collapsing

> **Pai e primeiro/último filho**
>
> *Se não houver `border`, `padding`, parte *inline*, contexto de formatação de bloco criado ou livre para separar o `margin-top` de um bloco do `margin-top` do seu primeiro bloco filho, ou nenhum `border`, `padding`, conteúdo `inline`, `height`, `min-height`, ou `max-height` para separar o `margin-bottom` de um bloco do `margin-bottom` do seu último filho, então essas margens colapsam. A margem colapsada acaba fora do pai.*

Já as margens laterais, na horizontal nunca vão colapsar! Veja o que diz a documentação oficial da W3C https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

> Horizontal margins never collapse.

Veja esse exemplo, repare que a margem só empurra para os lados quando o elemento é *inline* e nos elementos block empurra tb para os lado e na vertical. Veja que a margem horizontal não colapsa ela se soma a margem do elemento ao lado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Leia essa pergunta e a resposta: [Por que a Borda só afasta o elemento Horizontalmente e não Verticalmente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/329089/por-que-a-borda-s%C3%B3-afasta-o-elemento-horizontalmente-e-n%C3%A3o-verticalmente)

---

**Sobre as práticas para resolver o problema**

Existem sim várias formas de resolver esse problema, porém a maioria delas sempre tenta mudar o tipo do `display` do filho ou do pai. Mas a dica que eu te dou é usar o `overflow: auto;` assim vc não precisa se preocupar com o `model-box` e `display` dos elementos, o que pode gerar efeitos colaterais indesejados. Essa a a minha dica, pode ter gente que descorde, mas eu prefiro não mexer com o `display` do elementos, nem colocar `padding` ou `border` transparente para resolver isso...

Veja o seu exemplo aplicando o `overflow:auto` no pai

```css
body{
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
}
.topo{
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 130px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000000;
  overflow: auto;
}
.topo_caixa{
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<div class="topo">
  <div class="topo_caixa">
  </div>
</div>
```

Artigo interessante sobre `margin collapse` https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```css
body{
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
}
.topo{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #000;
}
.topo_caixa{
  margin: auto;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="topo">
<div class="topo_caixa">

</div>
</div>
```