# Quebras de medidas CSS

Tags: css, propriedade, height

Estou bem confuso como funciona as porcentagens de medida do `CSS` (em específico o %) e a propriedade *`height`*

```css
    html {
        border: solid 5px #000000;
        height: 600px;
        margin: 10px;
        
    }
    body {
        border: solid 5px #470eaf;
        height: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .app {
        border: solid 5px #ff0202;
        
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <div>Cabeçalho</div>
        <div>Corpo</div>
        <div>Rodapé</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Nesse código a *tag* `<body>`ultrapassa o `HTML`, por que isso acontece? Sendo que, eu defini a propriedade `HTML` como `600px`, o `body` não devia ir até `600px` e não ultrapassar esse valor? Já que a *tag* `<body>` tem seu pai como `<html>`, não deveria ser respeitado?

Edit1: Verifiquei que isso acontece com outros componentes filhos também:

```css
        html {
            border: solid 5px black;
            
        }
        body {
            border: solid 5px red; /*pai de .app*/
            height: 600px; 
        }
        .app {
            border: solid 5px violet; /*Filho de body*/
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .app div.cabecalho {
            border: solid 5px blue;
            
        }
        .app div.corpo {
            border: solid 5px blue;
        }
        .app div.rodape {
            border: solid 5px blue;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="app">
        <div class="cabecalho">Cabeçalho</div>
        <div class="corpo">Corpo</div>
        <div class="rodape">Rodapé</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Esse é um problema de *border collapse*, parte dele está descrito aqui: [Porque margin-top afeta a div pai](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/336980/porque-margin-top-afeta-a-div-pai)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas basicamente, o que acontece é que a margem padrão do `user-agent` do `body` não está *collapsando* com a margem padrão du `user-agent` do HTML, como isso vc tem uma diferença de 8px de altura aproximadamente (com borda de 1px fica mais fácil de ver), empurrando o `body` para fora do HTML, se vc colocar `margin-top: 0;` no `body` vc resolve o problema. Vc pode ler algo nesse sentido aqui [Por que "html, body" e não apenas "body" para eliminar as margens da página?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/275368/por-que-html-body-e-n%C3%A3o-apenas-body-para-eliminar-as-margens-da-p%C3%A1gina)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
html {
  border: solid 5px #000000;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 10px;

}

body {
  border: solid 5px #470eaf;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  margin-top: 0; /* isso corrige o problema */
}

.app {
  border: solid 5px #ff0202;

}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="app">
    <div>Cabeçalho</div>
    <div>Corpo</div>
    <div>Rodapé</div>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

---

**Sobre eu seu segundo exemplo**

É só  colocar a propriedade `box-sizing: border-box;` no container pai, assim a largura do `border` não se soma a  `height` de `100%` do próprio elemento.

```css
html {
  border: solid 5px black;
}

body {
  border: solid 5px red;
  /*pai de .app*/
  height: 600px;
}

.app {
  border: solid 5px violet;
  /*Filho de body*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;

  box-sizing: border-box; /* Isso resolve o problema */
}

.app div.cabecalho {
  border: solid 5px blue;

}

.app div.corpo {
  border: solid 5px blue;
}

.app div.rodape {
  border: solid 5px blue;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="app">
    <div>Cabeçalho</div>
    <div>Corpo</div>
    <div>Rodapé</div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

Bom isso parece estranho mas analise uma coisa , antes do body o que vem antes?
Tenta trabalhar com dives para ver se acontece o mesmo.

```
<html>
  <head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pai">
<div id="filho">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Geralmente usamos `id` para trabalhar com algo mais específico, infelizmente não é o caso da minha pergunta... A pergunta se refere a mais tipos de medidas, e não uma solução em geral. Pois se trabalho apenas em cima do `body` com a medida `height` ele respeita normalmente o `html`, porém o contrário (como citado na pergunta anteriormente) não funciona e gostaria de saber o por que.

Comment: Cara bem vindo ao pt.StackOverflow, cara explica melhor isso ai, pq mal da para entender o que vc escreveu, sua resposta não tem sentido algum...